# How can I access the width attribute of the embed object from within my application swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder

I have a flex 3 project with a root mx:Application. The width and the height are set to pct values, because the application has several sizes that can be chosen by the user, so the correct size is set on the embed's width attribute.

I'm trying to figure out how to access the value in that attribute. I read in several places that this.root.loaderInfo.width should give me that value, but it always returns 500, which I am guessing comes from the default application container width (see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62d75-7fff.html).

I realize I could pass it as a flashvar, but that is not a good solution in this case due to the nature of the project. I've also tried Application.application.width, stage.width, and stage.stageWidth, to name a few. I can't depend on any of those values, since they change based on the browser zoom level.

What I really need is the width attribute of the embed. Suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "since they change based on the browser zoom level" - are you sure about that? Did you do some tests to confirm it?

Comment: ExternalInterface it is! I realized I could add the callback function to the embed script. So now I call ExternalInterface from the swf after setting up the callback. Solution coming as soon as I can post it (after 8 hours).

Answer (score 1):

The width returned by `stage.stageWidth` depends on the [scale mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html) setting of the SWF. `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;`, which Flex uses, returns the size of the container. It's affected by both the embed size and the browser zoom level.

If `stage.scaleMode` is set to anything else, it will return the dimensions defined within the SWF, always returning the same value. And, as you mentioned, `loaderInfo.width` returns the dimensions set in the SWF, regardless of scale mode or embed dimensions. Unfortunately, there is no setting so that it is affected by the embed size, but *not* the browser zoom level.

The only way to find the dimensions of the container regardless of browser zoom level would be to pass it in as a parameter in the embed code, or use [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), like wvxvw mentions. I might go the flash var route—you are selecting between different layouts, so it's appropriate enough to have a setting instead of choosing implicitly based on the container size. Or, alternatively, you could choose the layout based on a range of dimensions/aspect ratios, instead of specific values.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I ended up going the ExternalInterface route, as the swf already lives in various pages in a way that wouldn't easily allow me to update the flashvars. Will post my solution once stack overflow lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up needing to use external interface. Here's the js I added to the js embed file:

```
function getSwfDimensions() {
    var swf = document.getElementById('myMovie');
    sendSwfDimensions({width:swf.width, height:swf.height});
}
function sendSwfDimensions(d) {
    thisMovie("myMovie").sendToActionScript(d);
}
function thisMovie(movieName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        return window[movieName];
    } else {
        return document[movieName];
    }
}
```

And in the flash:

```
private function getSwfDimensions():void {
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToActionScript", swfDimensionsReceived);
    ExternalInterface.call("getSwfDimensions"); 
}
public function swfDimensionsReceived(d):void {
    //set the width and height
    this._width = this.width = d.width;
    this._height = this.height = d.height;
    //set up a listener to handle browser zoom changes
    this.stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResize);
}
```

Comment: FYI ExternalInterface supports return values from JavaScript

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do that?